# How to get a single specific item from wordpress menu

Tags: php, html, wordpress

How can I get a specific item from a wordpress menu? The function `wp_nav_menu` returns all items, I want to get for example the second link in the list.

Function:

```
// HTML5 Blank navigation
function html5blank_nav()
{
    wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location'  => 'header-menu',
        'menu'            => '',
        'container'       => '',
        'container_class' => 'menu-{menu slug}-container',
        'container_id'    => '',
        'menu_class'      => '',
        'menu_id'         => '',
        'echo'            => true,
        'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
        'before'          => '',
        'after'           => '',
        'link_before'     => '',
        'link_after'      => '',
        'items_wrap'      => '<ul class="ul-menu"> %3$s </ul>',
        'depth'           => 0,
        'walker'          => ''
        )
    );
}
```

Output:

```
 <ul class="ul-menu">
    <li><a href="#">menu item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu item 3</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Desired output:

```
<li><a href="#">menu item 2</a></li>
```

Please Note: this must be a server-side solution, I'm not looking to target menu items through CSS or JavaScript.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: from what I remember you need to extend the `Walker_Nav_Menu` class with your own custom walker, you can then manipulate each item (and i guess extract one) see [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/116708/customizing-walker-nav-menu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu, $args)` instead.

In your case I believe

```
$args = array(
    'order'                  => 'ASC',
    'orderby'                => 'menu_order',
    'post_type'              => 'nav_menu_item',
    'post_status'            => 'publish',
    'output'                 => ARRAY_A,
    'output_key'             => 'menu_order',
    'nopaging'               => true,
    'update_post_term_cache' => false );

wp_get_nav_menu_items('header-menu', $args);
```

should return an array of menu-list objects. You could take the second one and put the content into a list item, or whatever you want to do with it.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items

Comment: thanks this helped but not quite what I wanted... ideally I want to create a function that would output the requested item, something like `get_menu_item(2);` which will output `<li><a href="#">menu item 2</a></li>` I just can't seem to figure out the logic to make it

Comment: what about something like
    `$items = wp_get_nav_menu_items('header-menu', $args);` 
`echo( '<li><a href="#">' . $items[1]["post_title"] . '</a></li>);`

Answer (score 0):

Nothing new in the logic, but I put the previous solution into a function that returns the output. That makes the code easier to read. You have to put the array of menu items into the function as an argument.

```
$menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_item( 'header-menu', $args );

echo get_menu_item( 2, $menu_items );

function get_menu_item( $item_number, $items ) {
  
   $output = '<li><a href="#">' . $items[ $item_number ][ "post_title" ] . '</a></li>';
   
   return $output;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to look at the data:

```
function nav_menu_example($items){
  foreach($items as $item){
    if ($item->post_title == '<your-nav-menu-item-name>') {
      // Do something with it...
      var_dump($item->post_title);
    }
  }
  return $items;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'nav_menu_example');
```